# how to reset password in oracle xe 12

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently installed oracle xe version 12 for study purposes and created a login id and password at the setup. But while logging in I found that TNS host was unreachable apparently as I used "@" in my password phrase can someone help me how to reset password!!??

Comment: you can have a @ in your password, just submit your password in "qu@tes"

Comment: While Jeff has given you a work-around, I would treat it as just that - a temporary work-around.  Once you get connected again, I'd urge you to change your password to one without '@'.  Also, '$' and '#' have also been shown to be problematic in various environments.

Comment: How do you mean a workaround? Having strong passwords is a good thing. And if you have bug numbers @EdStevensh happy to track down updates on those for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reset your password.

Simply put your password in "quotes" when you define your connection in SQL Developer.

[image]

Or if you do want to reset your password, simply right-click on your connection and do a 'reset password'

[image]

Be sure to quote it again when supplying the old/existing password.

Once you hit OK, we'll also update your connection properties to use the new password, so you don't have to re-key it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method (emphasize "alternate", not necessarily better or worse, is to connect as SYS and then change the password you are interested in:

```
C:> set ORACLE_SID=XE
c:> sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> alter user scott identified by tiger;
```